# Format grep output as CSV

Tags: linux, csv, grep

I'm not really good at Linux. I am using the next command to find some data:

```
svn info -R https://SOME_URL/TEST | grep 'Ruta: \|Fecha de último cambio: '
```

The output I'm getting looks like this:

```
Ruta: TEST
Fecha de último cambio: 2016-04-07 15:52:40 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)
Ruta: PRUEBA1.txt
Fecha de último cambio: 2016-04-07 15:16:19 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)
Ruta: PRUEBA2.txt
Fecha de último cambio: 2016-04-07 15:15:47 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)
```

But I need to present a report so I would like to see the output as CSV document, something like:

```
"Ruta";"Fecha"
"TEST";"2016-04-07 15:52:40 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)"
"PRUEBA1.txt";"2016-04-07 15:16:19 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)"
"PRUEBA2.txt";"2016-04-07 15:15:47 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)"
```

Is it possible to do that only with linux commands? Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with `sed`?

Comment: No, but I will search if you think that could help

Comment: `awk` is probably better for this.

Comment: or a simple pipe to `while read -r; do ... done`

Comment: If you're considering `a simple pipe to while read...` then make sure to read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice and various other articles on how to manipulate text with UNIX first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right tool for this job is awk, and you don't need grep when you're using awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 { fmt="\"%s\";\"%s\"\n"; printf fmt, "Ruta", "Fecha" }
sub(/^Ruta: /,"") { ruta=$0 }
sub(/^Fecha de último cambio: /,"") { printf fmt, ruta, $0 }

$ svn info -R https://SOME_URL/TEST | awk -f tst.awk
"Ruta";"Fecha"
"TEST";"2016-04-07 15:52:40 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)"
"PRUEBA1.txt";"2016-04-07 15:16:19 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)"
"PRUEBA2.txt";"2016-04-07 15:15:47 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a number of ways this can easily be done. You can either use your shell (any modern shell with *parameter expansion and substring removal*) or you can use `sed` or `awk` or any combination thereof.

You haven't specified the shell, but as long as you have a POSIX compliant shell, a short script can handle/parse the results of your svn command in a fairly easy manner. The following uses bash, but parameter expansion would work in any POSIX shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

fname="${1:-/dev/stdin}"  ## read from given filename or stdin (default)

echo "Ruta;Fecha"       ## print heading

while read -r line; do  ## for each line of input
    [ "${line%%:*}" = "Ruta" ] && echo -n "${line##* }" ## begins 'Ruta'
    [ "${line%%:*}" = "Fecha de último cambio" ] && {   ## begins "Fecha.."
        tmp="${line#*:}"
        echo ";${tmp:1}"
    }
done < "$fname"
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/ruta.txt
Ruta: TEST
Fecha de último cambio: 2016-04-07 15:52:40 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)
Ruta: PRUEBA1.txt
Fecha de último cambio: 2016-04-07 15:16:19 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)
Ruta: PRUEBA2.txt
Fecha de último cambio: 2016-04-07 15:15:47 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ cat dat/ruta.txt | bash parseruta.sh
Ruta;Fecha
TEST;2016-04-07 15:52:40 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)
PRUEBA1.txt;2016-04-07 15:16:19 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)
PRUEBA2.txt;2016-04-07 15:15:47 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)
```

To use with your command (after you make the script executable with `chmod 0755 scriptname`) you could do the following:

```
svn info -R https://SOME_URL/TEST | \
grep 'Ruta: \|Fecha de último cambio: ' | \
scriptname
```

(that is all one line above with the line continuations `'\'` at the end)

Give it a try and let me know if you have questions.

If you are limited to a POSIX shell (or shell without string indexing in the form `${var:start:end}`), then there is one command that would need to change. POSIX handles string indexing in a different manner, so you would need to change:

```
echo ";${tmp:1}"
```

to

```
echo $(expr substr "$tmp" 2 $(expr length "$tmp"))
```

in order to index the substring beginning with the date from the 2nd character after removing the `"Fecha..."` part.

Answer (score 1):

another awk alternative

```
$ awk -v q='"' 'NR==1{print q "Ruta" q ";" q "Fecha" q} 
             /^Ruta:/{t=q $2 q; next}
                     {sub(/[^:]+: /,"");
                      print t ";" q $0 q}' file 

"Ruta";"Fecha"
"TEST";"2016-04-07 15:52:40 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)"
"PRUEBA1.txt";"2016-04-07 15:16:19 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)"
"PRUEBA2.txt";"2016-04-07 15:15:47 -0500 (jue 07 de abr de 2016)"
```

Comment: Thanks! I already tested it and it worked perfect for my, thanks! I will start to learn awk, it will help me doing a lot of reports